# How to Access the stream of HoloLens 2 camera when trying to recognize the marker in AR app?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

I am beginner in unity and not so much used to HoloLens 2. Actually I am trying to make a simple AR app for HoloLens 2, when I connect the external camera it is working fine but when I want to access the stream of HoloLens 2 in recognizing the marker, it does not recognize the marker and I do not know that either the HoloLens 2 camera stream is working or not. I used the main camera as the child of MixedRealityPlaySpace and add some components from AR camera but it does not work then I tried AR camera separate and as a child of MixedRealityPlaySpace but still the HoloLens camera  stream is not working. It will be great help if anyone knows about the problems. Thanks In advance

Answer (score 0):

Which way  are you using for marker recognizing development? Vuforia or Unity AR foundation? Without any specific context the above information does not make any sense to me.

For AR Foundation, 2D Image tracking feature is not supported on HoloLens platforms for now, you can refer to this link to learn more about feature support per platform:[Platform Support](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.arfoundation@4.0/manual/index.html#platform-support).

For Vuforia,  there is a closed issue that show how to make Vuforia work with the MRTK: [What's the current status of using Vuforia with the MR Toolkit? #1461](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/1461)

Comment: I am trying to recognize marker through Vuforia and using HoloLens 2